# change combobox selection based on value in an object in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, flex3, combobox

how do i change the item selected in a combobox selection based on a selection of a datagrid object?

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the selectedItem property of the combobox to the dataGrid:

```
<s:ComboBox
  id="combo"
  dataProvider="{data}"
  selectedItem="{dg.selectedItem}" />

<mx:DataGrid
    id="dg"
    dataProvider="{data}"/>
```

Comment: but i want only a paricular feild from the datagrid to be selected

Comment: I don't quite understand. Perhaps you could provide a more elaborate description of your use-case?

Comment: selectedItem = "{dg.selectedItem['particularField']}"

Answer (score 0):

use the itemClick event on the datagrid to change the selection of the combo box.
You can find similar answer here [Itemclick event in datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972334/itemclick-event-in-datagrid)

Comment: it works for a text field but can you tell me how to implement it in a combo box?pls

Comment: I'd recommend using ListEvent.CHANGE event instead. ItemClick doesn't cover all methods of selection on the DataGrid/List, since the user can change selection via Keyboard.

Comment: bug-a-lot is right ListEvent.CHANGE is the best way to do it.